# What to import in an Angular module declaring a component with @input property?

Tags: angular

Angular 8.X

Before, I had all my components imported and declared in app.module.ts
And now Am making a module for every feature
But for components declaring @input I am getting the error:

```
**Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'device' since it isn't a known property of 'igwan-device-detail'.
1. If 'igwan-device-detail' is an Angular component and it has 'device' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'igwan-device-detail' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.**
```

my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'igwan-device-detail',
  templateUrl: './device-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-detail.component.scss']
})

export class DeviceDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() device: any;
  @Input() alert: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

my module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';


import { ParkManagementComponent } from './park-management/park-management.component';
import { DeviceDetailComponent } from './device-detail/device-detail.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [DeviceDetailComponent],
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule, MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule],
  exports: [DeviceDetailComponent]
})
export class DeviceSearchModule { }
```

Do you know what else needed to be imported ?